# General shortcut for going to parent folder in a tree view?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, operating-systems

Is there a general shortcut (e.g., in Windows or MacOS) that will make the current selection change to the parent item/folder of the currently selected item in a tree view?

Examples of the tree views I'm talking about: Windows Explorer file tree, Regedit in Windows, Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. It would be quite nice when you're very deep in a tree to just press something like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and go to the current selection's parent.

I doubt my question has an answer, but it would be nice if it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows it's the **left arrow** <kbd>←</kbd>.

If current node is foldable and expanded, left arrow will fold it. Otherwise it will navigate to its parent.

Comment: Wow, excellent! Edit: on second thought, the folding is a bit unfortunate.